# Postgresql slow query. Change query or posgresql.conf?

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

We have 3 tables.

10,000 rows in one and 80,000 rows in second and 400 rows in third.

Code was working well, but recently we met performance issues.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT "users_users"."id", "users_users"."email" 
FROM "users_users" WHERE (NOT ("users_users"."email" IN 
     (SELECT U0."email" FROM "users_blacklist" U0)) 
     AND NOT ("users_users"."id" IN (SELECT U0."user_id" 
FROM "games_user2game" U0))) ORDER BY "users_users"."id" DESC;
                                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan Backward using users_user_pkey on users_users  (cost=9.25..12534132.45 rows=2558 width=26) (actual time=46.101..77158.318 rows=2510 loops=1)
   Filter: ((NOT (hashed SubPlan 1)) AND (NOT (SubPlan 2)))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 7723
   SubPlan 1
     ->  Seq Scan on users_blacklist u0  (cost=0.00..8.20 rows=420 width=22) (actual time=0.032..0.318 rows=420 loops=1)
   SubPlan 2
     ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..2256.20 rows=77213 width=4) (actual time=0.003..4.042 rows=35774 loops=9946)
           ->  Seq Scan on games_user2game u0  (cost=0.00..1568.13 rows=77213 width=4) (actual time=0.011..17.159 rows=77213 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 77159.689 ms
(9 rows)
```

Main question: **Is it ok, that we meet performance issues on joining 2 tables with less than 100,000 rows?**

Where to dig? Should we change query or dig into db settings?

**UPD** Temporary solution, is to rid off from subqueries by prefetching them in code.

Comment: If I recall correctly, changing your query to use `Exists` rather than `in` can increase the performance

Comment: Which indexes are defined on the `users_users` table?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, indexes are defined on all fields, that plays in query. users_users has indexes on email and id.

Comment: OMG, yet another ORM addict ...

Comment: @wildplasser, question is not about ORM at all. We can write queries in raw sql. Question was about joining 3 tables with < 100,000 rows, and why performance on them are low.

Comment: "*indexes are defined on all fields*" says nothing about how many columns are in one index and in which order they appear in the index. And it doesn't tell us if the query could benefit from the index only scan introduced in Postgres 9.2

Comment: @NikolayFominyh: If you are serious about your request, please provide index definitions as requested and add table definitions (only the involved columns) as provided by pgAdmin or `\d tbl` in psql.

Comment: This is a very strangely written query...if you're using an ORM, I'd recommend ditching it.

Comment: @JackManey, already done without ORM.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the postgres dialet of SQL but it may be worth experimenting with outer joins. In many other dbms' they can offer better performance than subselects.

Something along the lines of

```
SELECT "users_users"."id", "users_users"."email"
FROM "users_users" us left join  "users_blacklist" uo on uo.email = us.email
                      left join "games_user2game" ug on us.id = ug.user_id
where uo.email is null
AND   ug.id is null
```

I *think* that is doing the same thing as your original query, but you'd have to test to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

I have run across similar problems on SQL Server, and rewritten the query with an exists, as @Scotch suggests to good effect.

```
SELECT 
    "users_users"."id", 
    "users_users"."email" 
FROM "users_users" 
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT NULL FROM "users_blacklist" WHERE "users_blacklist"."email" = "users_users"."email"
)
AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT NULL FROM "games_user2game" WHERE "games_user2game"."user_id" = "users_users"."user_id"
)
ORDER BY "users_users"."id" DESC;
```

This query will give you all users who are not blacklisted, and who are not in a game. It may be faster than the outer join option depending on how postgres plans the query.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like we have room for improvement in queries generated by orm, and 80,000 rows is not leading to scale issues yet.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if that leads to exactly the same execution plan. The Postgres query optimizer is quite smart

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name NOT IN and NOT EXISTS are not equal - In 9.x line Postgres is able to use better optimization (antijoin) for NOT EXISTS.